# Eloquent filtering pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot

I have authors and papers tables with many to many relationships. If I provide author's id in the request, how do I access only the papers which have this author_id in pivot table?

Comment: Can't you just do `Author::with('papers')->find($id);` ?

Comment: No, because one paper have more than one author and this way I will duplicate some papers. That's why I want to do Paper::with('authors') but I want to take only the papers that have the specific author in their authors relation.

Comment: I think I understand what you want, I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can add constraints to eager-loaded relationships like this :

```
Paper::with(['authors' => function($query){
    $query->where('id', $author_id);
}])->get();
```